# How do i make complete capsule in CSS

Tags: html, css

**I am trying to create the complete capsule in css but i am not getting the expected result. Can anynody help me to fix this issus. I am new in the css**

The following is my Code:

```
<style>
    #myStyle {
        position: relative;
        width: 60px; 
        height: 101px; 
        background: #f5d540;
        border-top-left-radius: 183px 150%;
        border-top-right-radius: 201px 147%;
    }
    #myStyle:after {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        display: block;
        content: '';
        width: 60px;
        height: 44px;
        border-radius: 44px 44px 0 0;
        background: white;
    }

</style>
<body ng-app="">
    <p> Insert Some text in the Text Field </p>
    <p> Enter The Text <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter the Name"> </p>
    <h1> Hi {{name}}</h1>
<div class="myStyle" id="myStyle">
    <h5 style="text-align:center;padding-top: 10px;"></h5>
</div>
</body>
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Actual Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  #myStyle { 
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid #94c640;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
 }
```

This will create a capsule

Answer (score 0):

below is updated snippet you can remove `#myStyle:after` and use `border-radius` for `#myStyle`.

```html
<style>
    #myStyle {
        position: relative;
        width: 60px; 
        height: 101px; 
        background: #f5d540;
        border-radius: 500px;
    }
    
</style>
<body ng-app="">
    <p> Insert Some text in the Text Field </p>
    <p> Enter The Text <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter the Name"> </p>
    <h1> Hi {{name}}</h1>
<div class="myStyle" id="myStyle">
    <h5 style="text-align:center;padding-top: 10px;"></h5>
</div>
</body>
```